# Docfx PDF Build in Azure DevOps

Tags: pdf, azure-devops, wkhtmltopdf, docfx

I have a docfx website that I have developed locally. I have added a pdf object in my docfx.json file in order to give a link for downloading the pdf of the website. I am using wkhtmltopdf for the same. It works fine locally and creates the pdf files, but when I use Azure DevOps build pipeline, the pipeline agent throws the following error:

```
[20-07-24 03:41:21.067]Error:[PDF]Error happen when converting {filename}.json to Pdf. Details: iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found.
```

my docfx pdf build looks like this:

```
"pdf": {
    "name": "ais",
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "index.md",
          "toc.yml"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "Cloud Readiness/**.md",
          "Cloud Readiness/toc.yml",
          "Migrate/**.md",
          "Migrate/toc.yml",
          "Workload Landing Zone/**.md",
          "Workload Landing Zone/toc.yml",
          "Plan/**.md",
          "Plan/toc.yml",
          "Strategy/**.md",
          "Strategy/toc.yml",
          "Backlog/toc.yml",
          "Backlog/**.md"
        ],
        "src": ".."
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "Cloud Readiness/**.png",
          "Cloud Readiness/**.jpg",
          "Migrate/**.png",
          "Migrate/**.jpg",
          "Workload Landing Zone/**.png",
          "Workload Landing Zone/**.jpg",
          "images/**.png",
          "Plan/**.png",
          "Plan/**.jpg",
          "Strategy/**.png",
          "Strategy/**.jpg",
          "Strategy/**.pptx"
        ],
        "src": ".."
      }
    ],
    
    "dest": "_site/static/files",
    "outline": "NoOutline",
    
    "noStdin": true,
    "keepRawFiles": true
  }
```

My Azure DevOps Build task config looks like this:
[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done?

Comment: I have tried mentioning nostdin inside the pdf object and set it to true, tried mentioning keeprawfiles as true, still it doesnt work on the pipeline. In local system it generates the pdfs without any problem.

Comment: Hi,
Please kindly share the build task and task configuration with us. We will check it and help you as soon as possible.

Comment: added in the original post.

Comment: Hi Souradeep,
I cannot see the second task in the devops pipeline, which extension are you using? Please kindly share the extension with us, in addition, do you mind share the debug log with us?